# simple-peer on.("signal") event repeats many times

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, webrtc, simple-peer

I'm using [`simple-peer`](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) to create a small video calling app using `NodeJS`, `SocketIO` and `Angular`

I'm trying to implement `full-mesh` here. I have a peer `initialtor` which will initiate the signal on loop.

My code is as below.

```
const peer = new SimplePeer({
    initiator: true,
    trickle: false,
    stream,
});

peer.on("signal", signal => {
    console.log(userToSignal, "signal-callerID");
    this.peerService.emit("sending signal", { userToSignal, callerID, signal })
})
```

This function will be in loop. when a new user conenct, It'll send the signal to that user, My problem is, `peer.on("signal", signal =>` event repeats itself even if there is only 1 user conencted, its making likle 11 requests on 1 peer create. whats the issue here and how can i fix it?

I'm refering to [this code](https://github.com/coding-with-chaim/group-video-final) and trying to implement this in angular.

Comment: Facing exactly same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

That is normal behavior, an offer and ice candidates. If you want just a single message set the trickle option to false as described [here](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer/#api). Note that this will incur additional latency in establishing the connection.

Comment: Hello. trickle is already false in both initiator and other one. i've shared the same code only.

Comment: so. how do i fix that. even if i have `trickle` disabled, `signal` event retuens multiple times.

Comment: first step is to dump the data it emits. If it includes candidates then trickle: false does not work.

Comment: hi i have the same issue.. did u figure out the cause/solution?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to ur client. I made Express webRTC app and find out that too much peers adding to my clients responsive peers array. So find out this code in [Issues](https://github.com/coding-with-chaim/group-video-final/issues/2). Btw try this.

```
socketRef.current.on("user joined", payload => {
        const item = peersRef.current.find(p => p.peerID === payload.callerID);
        if(!item) {
          const peer = addPeer(payload.signal, payload.callerID, stream);
          peersRef.current.push({
            peerID: payload.callerID,
            peer,
          })
          peers.push(peer);
        }
});
```

It worked for me. After resignal, peers wont add to ur array and u'll got ur video stream from another peer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. Just try with simple peer library version 9.6.2. It works!!!!!